# send phone's exact location to website

Tags: php, android, html, gps, location

I am developing an IOT project in which I need the exact location of my phone to be sent to my website. How can I send the phone's exact location to my website in a wireless mode? If there are any APIs or any other ways then suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: you have to write your own API to communicate between your app and server.

Comment: it's not quite clear what you're asking:  Are you asking how to use the android APIs to get the location from your device? or are you asking how to write an API to communicate with your server?

Answer (score 0):

you can get your current location from network provider and GPS and send lat,long in your server.

-NETWORK PROVIDER LOCATION

```
   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("Network", "Network");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                loc = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                            }
```

-get location based GPS

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                loc = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                              }
```

Above are few simple lines of code which successfuly returns location of user in loc object of Location class . By using this object we can easily get longitude and latitude of that location.

```
latitude = loc.getLatitude();
longitude = loc.getLongitude();
```